# Undefined when using a variable to get data from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get values from an object, but when I use a variable, the result is undefined. In this example foundSch is undefined if I use the variable but I get the object back if I type the value in directly.
https://codepen.io/justinlafountain/pen/poGWJVZ

```js
var routes = {
  northBoundWeekDay: [{
    station: "station1",
    times: ["7:00 AM", "7:20 AM", "7:40  AM", "8:00 AM", "8:20 AM"]
  }],
  ...
};

$("select").on("change", function() {
  var filterDirection = $("#direction").find(":selected").val();
  var filterDay = $("#day").find(":selected").val();

  var filteredSchedule = filterDirection + filterDay;

  console.log(filteredSchedule);

  var filteredSch = routes.filteredSchedule;

  console.log(filteredSch);

});
```

Comment: Variables must be in brackets.  Try `routes[filteredSchedule]`